# Should I thank the editor for accepting my paper?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

My paper has been accepted after several rounds of revisions. The editor him-/herself gave quite detailed comments some of which were quite important. Should I thank him/her personally for the acceptance of the paper and/or his effort(s) (the latter I have done before in my replies to reviews).

Answer (score 7):

I don't see anyone reason why you shouldn't. Although, don't thank them for accepting the paper. A good editor will accept an article by someone they dislike or they wholeheartedly disagree with but which makes a good argument. It's their job. It's not a favor to you personally.

In addition, you can mention it where you acknowledge everybody else who contributed with their comments. It's not uncommon to see papers whose authors thank editors or (anonymous) reviewers for their comments if they went beyond what is ordinarily expected of them.  This seems to be the case here.

Comment: The editor's name is presumably known, whereas reviewers aren't known. Should the editor be thanked by name? If so, then should their permission be sought first?

Comment: You can just write something like "I would like to thank XXX and the editor for his/her helpful comments on earlier versions of this text." or something like that. You don't have to mention the full name.

Comment: "don't thank them for accepting the paper" - I agree, although personally, I would probably thank them for the *message about the* acceptance.

Comment: Sure but that's just being polite. Just as you thank the barista at Starbucks for your coffee.

Answer (score 1):

It is proper etiquette, and accepted code of conduct in mathematical circles, to thank anyone who had contributed to your paper in a non-trivial manner. Hence, if the editor has made useful comments that improve your paper in some way, you could add a thank-you note to this effect in the final version. Something like "I thank the editor for useful suggestions/comments"